# Displaying hashtags from the db

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I have a problem, namely I want to display hashtags from such table "posts":

```
| id | author |   hashtags   |
|:------------|-------------:|
|  1 |  aaaa  | #aaa, #bbbb  | etc...
|  2 |  bbbb  | #ccc, #addd  |
|  3 |  cccc  | #aee, #ffff  |
```

The problem is that I would like to get something like this (only those records):

```
When I write a: #aaa, #addd, #aee
When I write b: #bbbb
etc...
```

How do I get the effect that only those hashtags that start with a letter (even in the same field) appear to me? I was thinking about regular expressions. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: comma separated values makes queries alot harder.. i advise you to normalize the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes:

- Move hashtags columns to a new table and store different hashtags in different rows (with post id as foreign key) i.e. normalize the table
- use `LIKE` operator to query on the new table, e.g.

  ```
  SELECT hashtag
  FROM post_hashtag
  WHERE post_id = <id>
  AND hashtag LIKE '%#a%';`
  ```

Comment: There's no need to store `#` in a hash table also.

Comment: I know, I know, but I wanted to avoid this solution

Comment: It's required in the output so we can either prefix each result with `#` or store it in table

Comment: @Trawlr you should not. This is the way to go for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You already see that your current way of storing hash tags failed. The proposed way is optimal solution for this.

Comment: I will do as you say @DarshanMehta Thank you all!